# How do I sort Python IndexError:List Index out of range when reading and writing with files

Tags: python, file, index-error

I'm working on a game in Python and at the end, scores are written to a file and then the top 5 scores are extracted from the file. This usually works perfectly fine but once I reset the high scores I get an Index error saying "the list index is out of range"
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/leo/Documents/Python/infinitest/infinitest.py", line 172, in <module>
    scoreboard()
  File "/home/leo/Documents/Python/infinitest/infinitest.py", line 147, in scoreboard
    print("{0[0]} : {1[0]}\n{0[1]} : {1[1]}\n{0[2]} : {1[2]}\n{0[3]} : {1[3]}\n{0[4]} : {1[4]}".format(scores,names))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How would I fix this

```
def scoreboard():
    c = add_up1(False)
    d = add_up2(False)
    with open("/home/leo/Documents/Python/infinitest/hi2.txt", "a+") as leaders:
        leaders.write('{},{}\n'.format(c,name1))
        leaders.write('{},{}\n'.format(d,name2))
        line=leaders.readline()
        dic={}
        for line in leaders:
            data = line.split(",")
            dic[int(data[0])] = data[1]
        dic1={}
        for key in sorted(dic.keys()):
            dic1[key]=dic[key]
        scores=list(dic1.keys())
        names=list(dic1.values())
        names =names[::-1]
        scores= scores[::-1]
        print("{0[0]} : {1[0]}\n{0[1]} : {1[1]}\n{0[2]} :{1[2]}\n{0[3]} : {1[3]}\n{0[4]} : {1[4]}".format(scores,names))
```

In the external file, it is formatted so there is the score, followed by a comma, followed by a 
username. For example:

```
100,exampleuser
```

The add_up functions are fine and just return the total score.
I've tried to add placeholder scores to fix the problem, like

```
1,Placeholder1
2,Placeholder2
3,Placeholder3
4,Placeholder4
5,Placeholder5
```

and this sometimes work but now is not working again.

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: You’re writing scores to a file, and then immediately reading what you wrote? Please include all relevant code and data in your post. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing to the file its *position* is at the end - you can see that with `leaders.tell()`. When you start reading, the for loop exits immediately because there are no more lines and `dic` remains empty. Later, `scores` and `names` are empty so you get an `IndexError` when you try to access items.

Before starting to read the file set it's position back to the beginning - if there is a header that you don't want skip the first line:

```
    ...
    leaders.seek(0)
    #_ = next(leaders)    # skip header
    for line in leaders:
        data = line.split(",")
        dic[int(data[0])] = data[1]
```